# Exponents in Binomial Distribution

Tags: distributions

Why do we have exponentials in equation of binomial distribution? What's the intuition of it?

[image: View Equation]

Comment: Because when events are independent their joint probability is calculated by multiplying the individual event probabilities, and all those are either `p` or `q`.  Q.E.D., the products are powers of `p` and `q`.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a (discrete) probability mass function $f_X$ of a random variable $X$ satisfies $$\sum_{k \in X} f_X(k) = 1,$$ where $f_X(k)$ is the probability that the random variable $X$ is equal to the given value $k.$ (I have admittedly for simplicity abused notation by writing $X$ as both a random variable and its set of outputs.)

By the Binomial Theorem, we can compute the powers of a sum of numbers by $$(p + q)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom n k p^k q^{n - k},$$ where the coefficient $\binom n k$ gives the number of ways to choose (without regard for order) $k$ elements from among a collection of $n$ elements. Labelling the probability mass function $f_X(k) = \binom n k p^k q^{n - k}$ and the random variable $X$ with outputs $\{0, 1, \dots, n \}$ and assuming that $q = 1 - p,$ indeed, we obtain a discrete probability distribution. We can check that $f_X(k)$ is a probability mass function sums to $1$: $$\sum_{k \in X} f_X(k) = \sum_{k = 0}^n f_X(k) = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom n k p^k q^{n - k} = (p + q)^n = 1^n = 1.$$

---

On the matter of intuition, one can be convinced by a simple counting argument: if we observe $n$ independent events such that either $P$ happens with probability $p$ or $Q$ happens with probability $q$ (i.e., not $P$ happens with probability $q = 1 - p$), then by the Multiplication Principle, the probability of witnessing $P$ a total of $k$ times is given by $p^k q^{n - k},$ as we must therefore witness $Q$ a total of $n - k$ times. Of course, you will notice immediately that this is an undercount: for $n = 2,$ we could have witnessed $P$ a total of $k = 1$ times in any of the $2 = \binom 2 1$ ways $PQ$ or $QP.$ Generally, in order to get the correct count, we must multiply by a factor of $\binom n k,$ i.e., the number of ways to choose (or observe) the event $P$ a total of $k$ times in $n$ trials.